# line graph renders wrongly and problem with the X axis (time), cannot brush the graph - time series dc.js

Tags: d3.js, dc.js, linechart

I'm creating a dashboard for a scanning tool. I have created a bunch of graphs but got stuck with plotting a line chart to show kind of like a time series ( like how many records are populated at that particular scan time). I'm using dc.js and have tried a couple of ways, but the line does not render correctly and the axis has weird thing going with it.

I cannot brush the graph too, it is throwing "coordinate-grid-mixin.js:1083 Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function".

I have a UNIX timestamp, which I'm converting to datetime and then I'm using these to plot the line chart.

[image: My present time series line graph image.]

```
//Converting the timestamp
var dateFormatSpecifier = "%m/%d/%Y";
var day_FormatSpecifier = "%d %b %y";
var dateFormat = d3.timeFormat(dateFormatSpecifier);
var dayFormat = d3.timeFormat(day_FormatSpecifier)
var dateFormatParser = d3.timeParse(dateFormatSpecifier);
var numberFormat = d3.format(".2f");


facts.forEach(function(d) { 
    console.log('Before Change : ' + d.timestamp);
    d.date = new Date(d.timestamp * 1000);

    d.month = d3.timeMonth(d.date);
    d.day = d3.timeDay(d.date);

    d.date = dateFormat(d.date);
    d.day = dayFormat(d.day)

    console.log('After Change : ' + d.date + ' ' + d.month + ' '+ d.day);
    // console.log('After Change Month: ' + d.month);
  });

//Plotting

var dateDim = data.dimension(function(d) { return (d.day);});
var groupForSNR = dateDim.group().reduceCount(item => 1);

var time_chart = dc.lineChart("#time-chart");

var minDate = dateDim.bottom(1)[0].date;
console.log('min : ' + minDate);
var maxDate = dateDim.top(1)[0].date;
console.log('max : ' + maxDate);

var xmin = dayFormat(new Date(1559890800*1000))
console.log('xmin : ' + xmin);
var xmax = dayFormat(new Date(1561878000*1000))
console.log('xmin : ' + xmax);

time_chart
    .height(150)
    .transitionDuration(500)
    .margins({top: 10, right: 10, bottom: 20, left: 40})
    .dimension(dateDim)
    .group(groupForSNR)
    .brushOn(true)
    .elasticY(true)
    .y(d3.scaleLinear().domain([0,100]))
    .x(d3.scaleOrdinal().domain(xmin, xmax))
    .xUnits(d3.timeDay);

    time_chart.xAxis().ticks(15);
    time_chart.yAxis().ticks(10);
```

### -

".x(d3.scaleTime().domain(xmin, xmax))" is not even displaying anything.

Comment: Hi, could you please look at [this example](http://dc-js.github.io/dc.js/examples/right-axis.html) and its source? Basically you will want to use Javascript date objects as your keys, then quantize to days (I presume) using `d3.timeDay`, specify `d3.timeDays` for `xUnits`. Seems like we need a proper tutorial for using time scales, since this keeps coming up...

Comment: Please give it a try and edit your question if you get stuck. Thanks!

Comment: I tried and stuck with a similar one again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for your effort.

Your syntax is slightly off, and you always want to work with JavaScript Date objects when using D3 time scales. Only the ticks and labels (output) will be formatted as strings, all input will be Dates.

`.domain()` always takes an array.

You want

```
var minDate = dateDim.bottom(1)[0].day; // Date object
var maxDate = dateDim.top(1)[0].day;

.x(d3.scaleTime().domain([minDate, maxDate]))
```

Not sure if these are the only problems - everything else looks okay but it's hard to tell without trying.

Just keep studying, look very closely at what the examples are doing, you'll pick it up quickly!

EDIT: you will find examples where the dates are formatted as strings with an ordinal scale on input. There are only particular cases where is this a good idea, and I don't think this is one of them.

Comment: Thanks @Gordon. The main Issue is my d.date field got converted to String and that is why when I use d3.scaleTime() it was not rendering. I fixed it and my chart is rendering. :-D

Comment: Yep, that's exactly it. Make sure that all the inputs are Dates. There usually isn't any reason to deal with strings on the input side, or to keep formatted dates around for any reason. If you feel that the answer set you on the right path, please click the green checkmark to accept the answer. Thanks!

Comment: Hey, @Gordon just one more follow up when I try to visualize with more than 1000 rows the webpage pauses and crashes. I found out this is just due to this line chart if I remove this everything seems normal and other graphs render fine. Do you know any workaround for this situation?

Comment: That's not normal at all. Crossfilter and dc.js can handle thousands of rows, up to maybe half a million as long as the data is properly aggregated. Most likely there is something else going wrong. Please open another question or a GitHub issue with a reproducible example.